# The apply family in R

Tags: r

```
    lapply(0:7 , function(i) choose(i,0:i))
```

I can see the output, yet cannot understand it. What is this line of code doing?
I do not understand lapply() at all.

[image: I have put the image of output in the link]

Comment: Perhaps you can find some clue from this https://www.r-bloggers.com/2016/03/apply-lapply-rapply-sapply-functions-in-r/#:~:text=lapply()%3A,the%20corresponding%20element%20of%20list.

Answer (score 0):

The `lapply` on 0:7, is looping over each element 0 to 7 in a `list`.  If we use the `I`, will return the value

```
lapply(0:7, I)
#[[1]]
#[1] 0

#[[2]]
#[1] 1

#[[3]]
#[1] 2

#[[4]]
#[1] 3

#[[5]]
#[1] 4

#[[6]]
#[1] 5

#[[7]]
#[1] 6

#[[8]]
#[1] 7
```

The `function(i)` is anonymous lambda function that returns the same output as above

```
lapply(0:7, function(i) i)
```

Then, we are creating a sequence from 0 to that value with `0:i` and `choose` the 'n', 'k' based on the 'i'

```
lapply(0:7, function(i) 0:i)
#[[1]]
#[1] 0

#[[2]]
#[1] 0 1

#[[3]]
#[1] 0 1 2

#[[4]]
#[1] 0 1 2 3

#[[5]]
#[1] 0 1 2 3 4

#[[6]]
#[1] 0 1 2 3 4 5

#[[7]]
#[1] 0 1 2 3 4 5 6

#[[8]]
#[1] 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

these are the 'k' that goes into `choose` while 'n' is the original element '0' to '7' for each `list` element

According to `?choose`

> The functions choose and lchoose return binomial coefficients and the logarithms of their absolute values. choose(*, k) uses direct arithmetic (instead of [l]gamma calls) for small k, for speed and accuracy reasons.